# How to search on 2 sets in aerospike database using java?

Tags: java, database, aerospike

Suppose I have 2 sets i.e. set 1 and set 2 where common bin is 'userid'

I want to get intersection of userid in both sets. How to achieve this in java?

Comment: You have n records in set1, some have userid bin.  Then you have m records in set2, some have userid. What do you mean by intersection? You want all records which have the same userid both in set1 and set2?

Comment: Yes. Think of it as join operation in SQL.

Comment: Don't think Aerospike natively supports that - you have to do the join in your application.